# unable to render boxplot to html page using python flask

Tags: python, pandas, flask

[image]

I am trying to render boxplot to html page using python flask. In the code i have imported excel sheet .xls to a data frame. On this dataframe have used pandas boxplot method to get box plot successfully. But when i am trying to render this box plot to html page using flask, i am able to see only box plot grid in html page and not actual box plot.

I have tried to save the box plot image first and then give its image source path in html page. but still unable to render it successfully to html page.

Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_file, make_response
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd
plt.style.use('ggplot')

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/do_box_plot/')

def do_box_plot():
    df = pd.read_excel('Path\\sfile_name.xls', sheet_name='Sheet1')
    df.boxplot(by = 'Programming_Language', column =['Entry_ProgrammingScore'], grid = True)
    bytes_image = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(bytes_image, format='png')
    bytes_image.seek(0)
    return send_file(bytes_image, mimetype='image/png')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index2.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <body>

      <h1>BOX PLOT VISUALIZATIONS FOR TEST SCORES</h1>

      <p>BOX PLOTS</p>

      <img src='/do_box_plot/' alt="Box Plot" height="442" width="442"> 

   </body>
</html>`enter code here`
```

Expect to render generated box plot to html page using flask. Could anyone help, thanks.

Comment: maybe file is empty and there is nothing to render. Do you have this problem with this file when you create plot without flask but using `plt.show()` ?

Comment: Without flask code below by adding plt.show() is able to generate boxplot:                    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from io import BytesIO
from itertools import islice
import pandas as pd
plt.style.use('ggplot')

df = pd.read_excel('path\\file_name.xls', sheet_name='Sheet1')
df.boxplot(by = 'Programming_Language', column =['Entry_ProgrammingScore'], grid = True)
plt.show()

Comment: you could add this information and code in question for other users. And you can remove imports which you don't need in code - like `matplotlib.backends.backend_agg` , `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d`

Comment: hi, As you said file is empty. I just tried only the python code to generate box plot. used plt.savefig('image.png') to save the image. Image is getting saved but is blank white image with no plot. But Plt.show() is displaying boxplot without any issues.

Comment: but you don't have problem to display it on web page ? You see grid and you have to add data to empty file to see plot. I'm not sure if there is no issue when you use `savefig` in different places - before or after `plt.show()`